# Area Calculation of Region A (Using Double Integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area, polar-coordinates

I'm calculating the area of the region $A$ defined by the following constraints:

$$ A = \{(x, y) \mid x^2 + y^2 \geq 2, \; x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x, \; y \geq 0\} $$

To calculate the area of the region $A$, we can set up the double integral in Cartesian coordinates as:

$$ A = \iint_A \ dx \ dy $$

The constraints $x^2 + y^2 \geq 2$ and $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x$ define region $A$ in the $xy$-plane. Additionally, the constraint $y \geq 0$ ensures that the region is above the $x$-axis.

Transforming to cylindrical coordinates, where $x = r \cos\theta$ and $y = r \sin\theta$, the constraints are expressed as $r^2 \geq 2$ and $r^2 \leq 2r \cos\theta$. The angle $\theta$ varies between $0$ and $\pi$ to address the upper half of the $xy$-plane.

The integral to calculate the area is:

$$ A = \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2\cos\theta} \ r \ dr \ d\theta $$

I appreciate any additional guidance or methods that can facilitate solving this integral and calculating the area of region $A$. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can you calculate the inner integral? The integral of $r$ is simply $r^2/2$.

Comment: Your angular bounds are not correct, but the other ones are fine.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I've been trying to determine the correct angular bounds, but I seem to be missing something. Why aren't the ones I posted correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this type of problem is by understanding the region.
$$x^2+y^2\ge 2$$ This means that is oytside of the circle of radius $\sqrt 2$ centered on origin
$$x^2+y^2\le 2x$$We can rewrite this:
$$x^2-2x+y^2\le 0\\x^2-2x+1+y^2\le 1\\(x-1)^2+y^2\le 1$$
This is the inside of the circle of radius $1$, centered on $(1,0)$.
It looks like this

[image]

Since you are outside of the red circle, your $\theta$ varies only between $0$ and $\pi/4$. Otherwise $r=2\cos\theta<\sqrt 2$.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your post is really helpful. Another thing that's causing me some trouble is that I've been trying to determine the correct angular bounds, but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Look at the intersection of the two circles. They meet at $(1,1)$, so the upper limit of $\theta$ is $\pi/4$. Otherwise the radius will be less than $\sqrt 2$, which contradicts the first inequality.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that the limits was  $\frac {7 \pi}{4}$ and  $\frac {\pi}{4}$ because $2 cos \theta = \sqrt 2$ give me $\theta$ =   $\frac {7 \pi}{4}$ or  $\theta$ = $\frac {\pi}{4}$ in $0$ to $2 \pi$

Comment: Then $\theta$ is between $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: That is correct.